# req.params does not work in mongo query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, request

this may be a bit difficult to explain, so I will be as clear as possible.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongo = require("mongodb");
const linkId = require("./newRoute");

const DBusername = process.env.username;
const DBpassword = process.env.password;

const numbersOnly = new RegExp('^[0-9]+$');

var linkArr = [];

router.get("/:url", function (req, res) {
    if (numbersOnly.test(req.params.url)) {
        mongo.MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function (err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("connection established")
            var cursor = db.collection("urls").find({ "id":linkId.id});
            cursor.forEach(function (doc, err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                linkArr[0] = doc.href;
            }, function () {
                db.close();
                res.redirect(linkArr[0])  
            })
        })
    } else {
        res.json({ "error": "This url is not on the database." })
    }
});
```

I am trying to query the database with an id number which will respond with a respective URL, and redirect to that URL. The database is filled with URLS and their respective id numbers. As you can see the code below will query the database with this line:

```
var cursor = db.collection("urls").find({ "id":linkId.id});
```

`linkId.id` is the id of the recently inserted URL imported from another file. And everything works perfectly. However if I use this line instead:

```
var cursor = db.collection("urls").find({ "id":req.params.url});
```

The cursor `forEach` never gets executed and I have access to the `req.params.url` so I don't get any errors. I don't want the id to be imported from a different file, I want the id (which is used to query the database) to be extracted from `req.params.url`. How come this isn't working, it's boggling my mind.

Comment: Are you sure that it is `id` and not `_id` while doing `find`? Also, if `req.params.url` is of type ObjectId, try doing this `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.url)`. I am not clearly getting the problem you are having, but I would recommend logging the values of variables to check if they are in the desired form.

Comment: I have logged the values and they are all in the desired from. `id` is a separate field, it is not `_id`it is a manually created id which is a random number. I have access to `req.params.url` (when I log it it is in correct form) but for some reason when I use `req.params.url` the `forEach `function for the cursor never runs.

Comment: I just solved it! @TarushArora it is because I had to convert `req.params.url` to a number before hand! `db.collection("urls").find({"id" : +req.params.url})` works

Comment: That's pretty cool

Comment: You'll probably want to consider having a long-running connection to MongoDB rather than starting one up on every request

Answer (score 1):

Very possibly because req.params.url is being passed as a string instead of a number. Mongo is very sensitive to data types and all items passed in req.params are considered strings with no casting. No values will be returned if a mongo document value is a number when querying for a string.

A plain text parser can help you with that like [mongo-qp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-qp)